# Android Speech Recognition API fails to recognize Android TTS

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, speech

**Objective**

I am currently developing an interactive application for the physically challenged children. As a part of this application, I want to demonstrate a functionality which allows mute children to understand voice search.

**Problem**

I have RecognizeSpeech class which converts speech to text and SpeakText class which converts text to speech. I have a handler class which seeks text input from user, runs RecognizeSpeech, uses SpeakText to convert input text into speech which is served as input for voice search. The problem is that the RecognizeSpeech class is unable to correctly convert the SpeakText output back to text.

I would like to know if there are specific languages in which Speech Recognition and TTS work perfectly back and forth? I would also like to know if the recognizer intent should be constructed in some other way which would solve the problem. Thanks.

**Code Outline**

```
class RecognizeSpeech extends Thread implements RecognitionListener {

        Intent intent;
        SpeechRecognizer sr;
        ArrayList<String> matches_text;
        static boolean stop;

        RecognizeSpeech(Context context) {
            sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context);
            sr.setRecognitionListener(this);
            intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,context.getPackageName());
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,3);
            sr.startListening(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            matches_text=results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            sr.stopListening();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
            matches_text=partialResults.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        }

        ...
}
```

The Text to Speech Code is as follows:

```
public class SpeakText implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    private TextToSpeech tts;
    String str;
    SpeakText mTTS;

    public SpeakText(Context context, String str) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
        this.str = str;
        tts = new TextToSpeech(context, this);
    }

    public boolean isSpeaking() {
        return tts.isSpeaking();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            } else {
                speakOut(str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ivona.tts&hl=no